# Как настроить Nginx 443 запрос с www редирект на без www

Tags: nginx, https, redirect

Как настроить конфиг Nginx чтобы все запросы по порту 443 c www переходили на nowww, попробовал добавить такую запись в начало конфига:

```
server {
        listen          443;
        server_name     www.site.ru;
        return          301 https://site.ru$request_uri;
}
```

Тогда сразу не работают оба сайта.

Comment: в эту секцию надо добавить и все директивы по обработке протокола ssl: [ssl_certificate и далее по списку](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html). а лучше — не делать новой секции, а добавить обработку для "www.site.ru" в уже существующую секцию. см.: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22792394/4827341

Comment: Спасибо, помогла разобрался.